# PowerShell: delete all files from a folder exclude xml files

Tags: powershell

I need a powershell line to delete all files in a folder excluding xml files.

Foldername:
`d:\apps\Que`

Subfolders should not be deleted

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to recursively delete files from subdirectories as well?

Comment: Only the files in the Que folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Remove-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7.2#example-2--delete-some-of-the-document-files-in-a-folder) supports native exclusion:

```
Remove-Item "d:\apps\Que\*" -Exclude *.xml
```

use `-WhatIf` to check what would be deleted without actually deleting it.

Comment: If I remember right, -Exclude only works in conjunction with -Recurse

Comment: @adv12 Don't think that's the case, but recursion isn't required anyway

Comment: Looks like you're right.  Don't remember how I got that impression.

Comment: This is the one I use now:  Remove-Item "d:\apps\Que\*.*" -Exclude *.xml